# Session variable not set in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session-variables

I have a Spring controller which is putting a variable in the session:

```
public class LoginFormController extends SimpleFormController {

    public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command) throws Exception {

            request.getSession().setAttribute("authenticated_user", "authenticated_user");
    }
}
```

I then have a HandlerInterceptor. In the preHandle method, I check for the variable in the session:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response,
                                      Object handler) throws Exception {

        /* first, check if the requested view even required authentication */
        if (isAuthenticationRequired(request)) {

            /* check to see that user is logged in */
            if (null == request.getSession().getAttribute("authenticated_user")) {
                forwardToLogonPage(request, response);
                return false;
            }
            /* all is ok - pass the request on */
            return true;
        }
        /* all is ok - pass the request on */
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is it seems that the session variable is not being set since request.getSession().getAttribute("authenticated_user")) is always resolving to null.

Any ideas plz?

Thanks,
Krt_Malta

Comment: Bdw...the isAuthenticationRequired method works well, I tested it.

Comment: The problem actually is the onSubmit() method is not being called...

Answer (score 0):

Try `throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(new ModelAndView("logonPage"))` instead of `return false`.

And in your logonPage, explicitly include the action in the form tag, something like this:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="login" action="logonPage.htm">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also inject the ServletRequestAttributes.
By including:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
```

I did this in an abstract super controller so all my controllers would be servlet request aware.

To extract the Request object you use can use the following

```
protected ServletRequestAttributes getServletRequest(){
    return (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
  }
```